# jQuery: Iterate through JSON object which has children and targeting them separately

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON structure

```
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "name": "Section 1",
      "pre": "Pre text",
      "post": "Post text",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "text_01": "Evidence 01",
          "text_02": "Evidence 02",
          "textarea_01": "Evidence 03",
          "textarea_02": "Evidence 04"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Section 2",
      "pre": "Pre text lad",
      "post": "Post text bro",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "text_03": "Evidence 05",
          "text_04": "Evidence 06",
          "textarea_03": "Evidence 07",
          "textarea_04": "Evidence 08"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The jQuery I have to iterate through it is:

```
$.getJSON( "/training/assets/json/test.json", function( data ) {
  $.each( data["sections"], function( key, val ) {
    console.log('[+] Top Level');
    console.log(val["name"]);
    console.log(val["pre"]);
    console.log(val["post"]);

    console.log('[+] Inputs');
    $.each( val["inputs"], function( k, v ) {
      $.each( val["inputs"][k], function( ke, va ) {
        console.log(ke + ' - ' + va);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

This spits out the following which is what I want but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to achieve the same?

[image]

Comment: I'm not clear on what the objective is - if it's just outputting the contents of JSON to the console then why not just dump it using `console.log(...)` or `console.dir(...)`? What is the `items` array used for?

Comment: items has now been removed - I want to be able to create a form dynamically so would need to have the name, pre, the text fields and textareas and then the post

Answer (score 1):

'Cleaner' is a very subjective term, but you can make the code more succinct by using arrow functions along with `Object.entries` to for the inner loop.

In addition you can access the object's properties by name instead of bracket notation.

Finally you can use `forEach()` instead of jQuery to loop. In fact jQuery is not needed at all.

```js
let data = {sections:[{name:"Section 1",pre:"Pre text",post:"Post text",inputs:[{text_01:"Evidence 01",text_02:"Evidence 02",textarea_01:"Evidence 03",textarea_02:"Evidence 04"}]},{name:"Section 2",pre:"Pre text lad",post:"Post text bro",inputs:[{text_03:"Evidence 05",text_04:"Evidence 06",textarea_03:"Evidence 07",textarea_04:"Evidence 08"}]}]};

data.sections.forEach(section => {
  console.log('[+] Top Level');
  console.log(section.name);
  console.log(section.pre);
  console.log(section.post);
  
  section.inputs.forEach(input => {
    Object.entries(input).forEach(item => console.log(`${item[0]} - ${item[1]}`));
  });
});
```